# javascript require ewelink-api not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use javascript for the first time and can't seem to get a script running correctly from a bash shell on the command line.

I want to make calls from bash on a server in the cloud to ewelink.cc (a home automation website via an API).  The toolset to do this seems to be written in javascript.  So I am trying to set it up from my script to open a garage door using the ewelink website.

My server in the cloud system is Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

```
# node -v
v10.15.3
```

I am trying to use the following script from github:

```
https://github.com/skydiver/ewelink-api
```

**ewelink-api** is written in javascript and is meant to connect through the ewelink api to devices that I have configured into their IOT ecosystem, like my garage door.  In fact, I can currently control my garage door through the app on my phone so all of that is set up correctly.

This is the script I am running.  It is called ewelink.js.  It is a sample script provided in the ewelink-api package from github.

```
const ewelink = require('ewelink-api');

/* instantiate class */
const connection = new ewelink({
  email: 'blah@blah.org',
  password: 'blahblah',
  region: 'us'
});

/* get all devices */
const devices = await connection.getDevices();
/* const devices = connection.getDevices();  */
console.log(devices);
```

Here is how I am calling the script and the results:

```
# node ewelink.js
/root/node_modules/ewelink.js:11
const devices = await connection.getDevices();
                ^^^^^

SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
    at new Script (vm.js:80:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:274:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:326:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:664:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:712:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:600:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:539:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:531:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:754:12)
    at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
```

Because of the **require('ewelink-api')** I *think/guess* that the ewelink.js script that I am running should be in the same directory as the **ewelink-api** directory.  Is this correct?

Because I am a javascript noob, I know there is something stoopid I am doing here that is keeping it from working.  I have tried to execute the script in other directories and get the same results.

The guthub documentation for the project makes some pretty high assumptions about me, the reader, and my javascript skillset.

### UPDATE

In my effort to RTFM, on https://nodejs.org/en/knowledge/getting-started/what-is-require/ I find this nugget:

> The rules of where require finds the files can be a little complex, but a simple rule of thumb is that if the file doesn't start with "./" or "/", then it is either considered a core module (and the local Node.js path is checked), or a dependency in the local node_modules folder. If the file starts with "./" it is considered a relative file to the file that called require. If the file starts with "/", it is considered an absolute path. NOTE: you can omit ".js" and require will automatically append it if needed. For more detailed information, see the official docs.

So I updated the require to his:

```
const ewelink = require('./ewelink-api');
```

And I get the same results.  Full disclosure, I am trying to work in this directory:

```
# pwd
/root/node_modules
```

In that directory, is the ewelink.js file that I am trying to work with and the **ewelink-api** directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the ewelink.js script that I am running should be in the same directory as the ewelink-api directory. Is this correct?

This is incorrect. Because the string in the `require()` call is not a path, it will use the [`ewelink-api`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ewelink-api) package from https://www.npmjs.com/, not any of your local packages. So it doesn't matter where you run the script from.

`const ewelink = require('ewelink-api');`

Like the error says, the `await` keyword is only available within an async function. The async/await feature essentially allows you to write asynchronous code in a synchronous-looking fashion.

To make your code work, the simplest way is to encapsulate your code inside an asynchronous function and instantly run it.

```js
const ewelink = require('ewelink-api');

(async () => {
  const connection = new ewelink({
    email: 'blah@blah.org',
    password: 'blahblah',
    region: 'us'
  });

  /* get all devices */
  const devices = await connection.getDevices();
  /* const devices = connection.getDevices();  */
  console.log(devices);
})();
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now I'm off to the races!

Comment: Not sure if the made this example on intentional wrong. Thanks anyway!

Comment: https://ewelink-api.vercel.app/docs/demos/serverless contains the correct example